# perl look_down tag index

Tags: html, perl

I'm trying to get the text only in the second li. How am I going to do that in look_down. Thanks in advance :)

```
 <ul class="threads">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul class="threads">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul class="threads">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$tree->parse($url);

foreach my $ul ($tree->look_down(_tag => 'ul', class => 'threads')){
    foreach my $li ($ul->look_down(_tag => 'li')){
        print $li->as_text. "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy with https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $html = q{<ul class="threads">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul class="threads">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul class="threads">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>};


my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse_content( $html );
for my $sec ( $tree->findnodes( q{    //ul[@class='threads']/li[2]    } ) ){
    $sec->dump;
}
__END__
<li> @0.1.0.1
  "two"
<li> @0.1.1.1
  "two"
<li> @0.1.2.1
  "two"
```

This helps you if you don't know xpath yet :) [Re: htmltreexpather.pl - xpath helper, creates xpath search strings from html ($VERSION = 20120112 )](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=947532)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. This program first finds all the `ul` elements with a `threads` class attribute. Then all the `li` descendants are found for each of these, and the second one printed as text

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(\*DATA);

for my $ul ($tree->look_down(_tag => 'ul', class => 'threads')) {
  my @li = $ul->find('li');
  say $li[1]->as_trimmed_text;
}

__DATA__
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page title</title>
  <head>
  <body>
    <ul class="threads">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <p>para</p>
    </ul>
    <ul class="threads">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="threads">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### output

```
two
two
two
```

#### Alternatively

Here is an alternative, more concise solution using [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

Note that I have omitted the `DATA` section, which is the same as above

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(\*DATA);

for my $li2 ( $tree->findnodes('//ul[@class="threads"]/li[2]') ) {
  say $li2->as_trimmed_text;
}
```

The output is identical to that of the code above